# Magento case in sensitive search

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, catalog, search

I am searching all customers having provided name. But the "addAttributToFilter" is not giving the desired result. My code ignores the match and only return exact words. Here is my code

```
$client_name = (isset($_REQUEST['client_name'])) ? $_REQUEST['client_name'] : "";
$usersCollection = mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('group_id', '4')
    ->addAttributeToFilter(
    array(
        array('attribute' => 'firstname', array('like' => '%' . $client_name . '%')),
        array('attribute' => 'middlename', array('like' => '%' . $client_name . '%')),
        array('attribute' => 'lastname', array('like' => '%' . $client_name . '%')), ));
```

I'll post client name let say I posted "zain". Then it should return all customers having name zain. The query should return "Zain" "zain" "ZAIN".

Comment: Please explain what you want as result.If possible add example in question

Comment: I'll post client name let say I posted "zain". Then it should return all customers having name zain. The query should return "Zain" "zain" "ZAIN".

Comment: Some code changes are required here only:
array('attribute' => 'firstname', array('like' => '%' . $client_name . '%'))

Answer (score 1):

try this solution may be work in your case. it worked for me

```
$usersCollection = mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection()
   // ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    //->addAttributeToFilter('group_id', '4')
    ->addAttributeToFilter(
    array(
        array('attribute' => 'firstname', array('like' => '%' . $client_name . '%')),
        array('attribute' => 'middlename', array('like' => '%' . $client_name . '%')),
        array('attribute' => 'lastname', array('like' => '%' . $client_name . '%')), ));

     $allids=$userCollection->getAllIds(); //get all ids

$newusersCollection = mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('group_id', '4')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $allids));
```

Answer (score 0):

I have checked this code it's working fine, I have only doubt on this line

```
->addAttributeToFilter('group_id', '4')
```

Comment this line and check again and make sure all your provided user should be in same group if you are apply this filter other wise this code will not work.

Comment: Yes you're right. But the problem is I want to display all users whose name matches in first name or last name or middle name.
I want to display all of them. This code isn't right

Comment: As i have mention in my answer if you want to get all user then just comment ->addAttributeToFilter('group_id', '4') this line

Answer (score 0):

Use below code:

```
<?php
$client_name = (isset($_REQUEST['client_name'])) ? $_REQUEST['client_name'] : "";
$usersCollection = mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter(
    array(
        array('attribute' => 'firstname', array('like' => '%' . $client_name . '%')),
        array('attribute' => 'middlename', array('like' => '%' . $client_name . '%')),
        array('attribute' => 'lastname', array('like' => '%' . $client_name . '%')), ));

        foreach($usersCollection as $child){
            echo $child->getId().$child->getName();

        }

        ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Guys thanx alot for your answers BUT I am afraid none of the answer solved my issue. Dear friends the "addAttributeToFilter" is having some issue. Group id is not the problem. Just for clarification I've removed group id but still cannot get customer. This is new code:

```
$usersCollection = mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection()
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                ->addAttributeToFilter(
                array(
                    array('attribute' => 'firstname', array('like' => '%' . $client_name . '%')),
                    array('attribute' => 'middlename', array('like' => '%' . $client_name . '%')),
                    array('attribute' => 'lastname', array('like' => '%' . $client_name . '%')),
        ));
```